# How to make tex appear in the middle of a line in Lyx?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, lyx

When I write, for example, in Math.SE and I want some equation to appear in the middle of the line I just use

> $$

instead of just one dollar sign.

How can I do something similir in Lyx ? doing something like ctrl+M twice didn't work.

Comment: If there are any other relavant tags plase add them, I am not very firmilir with tags here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an unnumbered equation, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, or Insert --> Math --> Display formula.

If you want a numbered equation, you can either

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> (Note: Release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd> keys before hitting <kbd>N</kbd>.)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, then right click it and choose Number this formula.
- Insert --> Math --> Numbered formula

If you want several equations after one another, use one of the AMS environments, either `gather` or `align`. The latter lets you align after e.g. the equals sign in each line. Both of these are found in Insert --> Math menu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it for unnumbered equation and it worked. Did you mean that if I want to number an equation after this I can do so by Alt+mn ? if so, the combination did not work for me (it tried to open the Navigation tab)

Comment: @Belgi Yes, but you have to release the Alt key before pressing N. (Sorry, should perhaps have mentioned this.) So hold down Alt and press M, then release everything, and press N.